# C# Converting Bitmap to Emgu Mat always fails

Tags: c#, visual-studio, opencv, emgucv

I'm trying to convert a bitmap to mat to use for OpenCV.
But for some reason they wouldn't let me convert it.
I found the code below here on Stack and seen it on many other sites as well.

Does anyone here have an idea why it doesn't work?

*Cannot convert "System.Drawing.Bitmap" to "byte[ , , ]".*

Just as a note, at the beginning 8 screenshots are taken of set coordinates, these are saved as a bitmap and should then be converted to mat.

Please take a look at the embedded image.

```
  public static Image<Bgr, byte> FromFile = new Image<Bgr, byte>("MyImage.jpg");
    Mat mat = FromFile.Mat; // Only a way to convert it succesfull,  
                            // but isnt the way i want to go.


    public static Bitmap skillQ;
    public static Image<Bgr, byte> FromBitmap = new Image<Bgr, byte>(skillQ).ToImage; 
    Mat mat2 = FromBitmap.Mat;         

   
    
    //public static Image<Bgr, byte> FromBitmap = new Image<Bgr, byte>(skillQ).ToImage;
```

This Image shows the Error Message.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are not converting your image into a `Mat` but into a `Image<>` (more info about the difference and what a Mat is [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d6d/tutorial_mat_the_basic_image_container.html)).

To convert any image from file into a `Mat` you can simply use the following:

```
  Mat fromFile = new Mat("test.bmp");
```

To convert a `Bitmap` to `Mat`you can install the NuGet `Emgu.CV.Bitmap` that add some extensions to faclitate the conversion to `Bitmap`.

```
Bitmap bitmapTest = fromFile.ToBitmap();
Mat fromBitmap = bitmapTest.ToMat();
```

Comment: thanks a lot. i found the correct answer already by asking my lecturer, but it was exactly what you said.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use this method that converts it for you,
this method worked very well for me.

The Method:

```
static void BitmapToMat(Bitmap bitmap, Mat mat)
{
    BitmapData bmpData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    CvInvoke.CvtColor(new Mat(bmpData.Height, bmpData.Width, DepthType.Cv8U, 3, bmpData.Scan0, bmpData.Stride), mat, ColorConversion.Bgr2Bgra);
    bitmap.UnlockBits(bmpData);
}
```